# Overload the += event operator

Tags: c#, events, operator-overloading, overloading, event-listener

Is there  a way to overload the event += and -= operators in C#?  What I want to do is take an event listener and register it to different events.  So something like this:

```
SomeEvent += new Event(EventMethod);
```

Then instead of attaching to SomeEvent, it actually attaches to different events:

```
DifferentEvent += (the listener above);
AnotherDiffEvent += (the listener above);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not really overloading, but here is how you do it:

```
public event MyDelegate SomeEvent
{
    add
    {
        DifferentEvent += value;
        AnotherDiffEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        DifferentEvent -= value;
        AnotherDiffEvent-= value;
    }
}
```

More information on this on [switchonthecode.com](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-event-accessors)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this In C# using [**custom event accessors**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx).

```
public EventHandler DiffEvent;
public EventHandler AnotherDiffEvent;

public event EventHandler SomeEvent
{
    add
    {
        DiffEvent += value;
        AnotherDiffEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        DiffEvent -= value;
        AnotherDiffEvent -= value;
    }
}
```

Which means you can simply call `SomeEvent += new EventHandler(Foo)` or `SomeEvent -= new EventHandler(Foo)` and the appropiate event handlers will be added/removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine delegates using + and - operators

See [How to: Combine Delegates (Multicast Delegates)(C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx)

Answer (score -4):

If you are just looking to get away from some typing, you can do this

```
SomeEvent += MyMethod;
```